# nfcpy: "Symbol not found"?

Tags: python, macos, nfc

I've install nfcpy via pip, but am struggling to set it up. While running in the python shell, the following error comes up:

```
>>> import nfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nfc/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from clf import ContactlessFrontend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nfc/clf/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import nfc.llcp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nfc/llcp/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from llc import LOGICAL_DATA_LINK, DATA_LINK_CONNECTION
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nfc/llcp/llc.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import sec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nfc/llcp/sec.py", line 490, in <module>
    OpenSSL = OpenSSLWrapper(libcrypto)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nfc/llcp/sec.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.crypto.EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates.restype = c_int
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7f81ca493370, EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates): symbol not found
```

What's the meaning of this error message, and how could it be fixed?

For reference, I am using the following configuration:

- OS: Mac OSX 10.10.5
- NFC Reader: RC-S380
- Python 2.7.10
- pip 8.1.2
- nfcpy (0.11.1)

Comment: Your homebrew python is either misconfigured or cannot find all the required dependencies. I'm guessing that it's your OpenSSL (or lack of)... you'll probably need to install the real deal instead of the wrapped libcrypto.

Comment: @l'L'l When I hit `which python`, I get `/usr/local/bin/python`. I assume this is python downloaded and installed from the official source.

Comment: The python that is native to OS X is located at `/usr/bin/python`... also in your log message `/usr/local/Cellar/python/ ...` is a clear indication that it's the homebrew version. The python likely isn't the main issue; it's the OpenSSL.

Comment: @I'L'I How is OpenSSL an issue in this case?

Comment: In the traceback: OpenSSL = OpenSSLWrapper(libcrypto), (EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates: symbol not found). The issue likely arises because newer versions of OS X don't include the necessary OpenSSL lib/headers which the installed module is seemingly counting on.

Comment: Is that fixable by installing a version of OpenSSL including those lib/headers? If so, where do I obtain it from?

Comment: I would imagine it couldn't hurt (whether or not it fixes the issue we'll see, as there's sometimes potential issues elsewhere). You can either install OpenSSL via homebrew, Macports, or compile and build the library yourself. Since you're already using homebrew that might be the recommended route, and allows you to uninstall it easily if you wanted.

Comment: Yep, I got it working by install the latest version of OpenSSL via homebrew and running `brew link --force`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The below is a restatement of @I'L'I 's correct answer from the comments:

Your homebrew python is lacking the required OpenSSL dependencies. You can install OpenSSL via homebrew, Macports, or compile and build the library yourself.